# Help understanding equations of motions for a line element in their full generality

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, variational-principle, variational-calculus

(Note: I am crossposting this from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3740738/)

Let us work with these definitions $L=\sqrt{dAdB}$ and $S[A,B]=\int_{\Delta \lambda}\sqrt{\frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}} d\lambda$. Here I consider $A$ and $B$ to be general commutating quantities, and $\lambda$ is an arbitrary parametrization.

- For instance, if $A=\overline{B}$, then $dAdB$ would be the "complex norm/ or metric" written as $dAdB=d\overline{A}dA$.
- If $B=A=\sigma_x X +\sigma_y Y + \sigma_z Z$ (Pauli matrices), then $dAdB= (dX)^2+(dY)^2+(dZ)^2$, or the Euclidean metric.
- If $A=X^\mu$ and $B=X_\nu$, then we have general curvilinear space, etc.

Let us now consider a Lagrangian of the form $L=\sqrt{dAdB}$. The Euler-Lagrange equations of motions for:

$$
S[A,B]=\int_{\Delta \lambda}\sqrt{\frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}} d\lambda
$$

are

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A}= \frac{1}{4 \left( \frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \right)^{3/2}}  \left(- \frac{\partial^2 A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda^2} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} +  \frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial^2 B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}^2 \right) \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \tag{1}
$$

---

For reference, I include my derivation here:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A} &= \frac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{\partial }{\partial (\partial A/\partial \lambda)} \sqrt{\frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}} \\
&=\frac{d}{d\lambda} \left( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}}} \frac{\partial }{\partial (\partial A/\partial \lambda)} \left( \frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \right) \right)\\
&=\frac{d}{d\lambda} \left( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}}}  \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \right)\\
&=\frac{d}{d\lambda} \left( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}}} \right) \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} +\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}  \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}}}  \frac{d}{d\lambda}  \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}  \\
&= \frac{-1}{4 \left( \frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \right)^{3/2}}  \frac{d}{d\lambda} \left( \frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}  \right) \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} +\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}  \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}}} \frac{\partial^2 B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda^2} \\
&= \frac{-1}{4 \left( \frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \right)^{3/2}}  \left( \frac{\partial^2 A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda^2} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} +  \frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial^2 B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}^2 \right) \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} +\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}  \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}}} \frac{\partial^2 B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{4 \left( \frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \right)^{3/2}}  \left(- \frac{\partial^2 A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda^2} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} +  \frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial^2 B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}^2 \right) \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

---

Now, I am trying to understand the meaning of (1) - to visualize what is happening so to speak, but to do so by avoiding taking "special case simplifications/shortcuts". For instance, to derive the geodesic equations one often either takes $L\to L^2/2$, the "kinetic approach", or removes the square root denominator by affine parameterization, etc. Then one interprets the resulting equation post-application of the "shortcut". But, surely there are insights to be gained from investigating the structure of the general equations of motions without taking any "shortcut"? Can we investigate each term of (1) and give physical meaning? For instance:

1. Can we consider the term $ \frac{1}{4 \left( \frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \right)^{3/2}} $ to be a type of normalization factor?
2. Can we interpret the term $\left(- \frac{\partial^2 A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda^2} \frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} +  \frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial^2 B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}^2 \right)$ as a current -- the resemblance to a probability current is even more apparent if A is the complex conjugate to B. However it differs from it because we get second derivatives whereas the probability current as the same matheamtical form but over first-order derivatives. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current. Is an equation of this form but involved second-order derivates instead of first-order derivates still a type of current? Is it a velocity current?
3. Is there a general connection between (1) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current#Connection_with_classical_mechanics where the probability current is connected to $\nabla S=j$.

---

Althought this is not the case of my primary interest, I will mention that if I allow myself to pose $\partial L /\partial A=0$ (shortcut), then the equations simply considerably to:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda^2}\frac{\partial B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}-\frac{\partial A[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda}\frac{\partial^2 B[\lambda]}{\partial \lambda^2}=0
$$

This may give an hint to understand the general case better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term on the right-hand side of equation (1) is a curvature, this is measuring the angle between the first derivative and the second derivative, if the first and second derivative are parallel to each other then the right-hand side vanishes identically. The cubic term is there as well in the definition of the curvature [Curvature-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#:%7E:text=to%20the%20curve.-,Plane%20curves,vector%20to%20the%20curve%20rotates.), this term is a normalization factor necssary due to the fact that the curve is not arc-length parametrized.

What your equation of motion is telling you is that the shortest path between the two points (limits of the integral) is the one without curvature.

Comment: WOW! you are right. It is the curvature! It seems the only difference is that the right-hand side of my equation as the extra term $\partial B[\lambda]/partial \lambda$. Can you explain what that one is?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this pieces are there because your arc-length is not written as the square of something under some metric, I believe these factors for both equations of motion can be ignored since if they are to be zero the whole action would vanish.